# How to put map annotations dynamically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mapkit

I'm creating map with multiple annotations but I don't know how dynamically (I have them in CoreData).

I'm puting them fixed with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    CLLocation *userLoc = mapView.userLocation.location;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoordinate = userLoc.coordinate;

    NSLog(@"user latitude = %f",userCoordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"user longitude = %f",userCoordinate.longitude);

    mapView.delegate=self;

     NSMutableArray* annotations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];




    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate1;
    theCoordinate1.latitude = 43.82078;
    theCoordinate1.longitude = 15.307265;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate2;
    theCoordinate2.latitude = 44.91035917;
    theCoordinate2.longitude = 14.65576172;



    MyAnnotation* myAnnotation1=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];

    myAnnotation1.coordinate=theCoordinate1;
    myAnnotation1.title=@"Rohan";
    myAnnotation1.subtitle=@"in the city";

    MyAnnotation* myAnnotation2=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];

    myAnnotation2.coordinate=theCoordinate2;
    myAnnotation2.title=@"Vaibhav";
    myAnnotation2.subtitle=@"on a Bridge";



    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation1];
    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation2];


    [annotations addObject:myAnnotation1];
    [annotations addObject:myAnnotation2];


    NSLog(@"%d",[annotations count]);
    //[self gotoLocation];//to catch perticular area on screen
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    // Walk the list of overlays and annotations and create a MKMapRect that
    // bounds all of them and store it into flyTo.
    MKMapRect flyTo = MKMapRectNull;
    for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in annotations) {
        NSLog(@"fly to on");
        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0);
        if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo)) {
            flyTo = pointRect;
        } else {
            flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, pointRect);
            //NSLog(@"else-%@",annotationPoint.x);
        }
    }


    // Position the map so that all overlays and annotations are visible on screen.
    mapView.visibleMapRect = flyTo;


    UIBarButtonItem* temp=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
    temp.title=@"Back";
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=temp;
    //[temp release];
}
```

P.S. If you need extra code just tell.

Thank's for help

**UPDATE:**

**Locations.h**

```
...
@interface Locations : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * lat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * lon;
...
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is example code where I'm puting annotations "fixed".

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/77033905/stackoverflow/Map.zip

How can I add this annotations over array? Define this locations(coordinates,title, subitle in array and add them to map.)

Comment: what does your dynamically mean?

Comment: In PHP I put them like this: $array[] = $annotation; and etc.

Comment: still don't know. Just let me what you exactly wanna do.

Comment: could you plz show us the core data class?

Comment: Can you pls create an array and put several annotations in it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11658/discussion-between-croios-and-lu-yuan)

Answer (score 0):

the location instance will be your annotation just do

```
[mapView addAnnotations:locationArray];
```

**Location.h**

```
...
@interface Locations : NSManagedObject <MKAnnotation>{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * lat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * lon;
...
```

**Location.m**

```
...
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
coordinate.latitude = [self.lat doubleValue];
coordinate.longitude = [self.lon doubleValue];
return coordinate;
}

- (NSString *)title
{
return @"yourTitle";
}

- (NSString *)subtitle
{
return @"yourSubtitle";
}
```

Is this what your want?

Comment: sorry, but no. I want to add annotations over my code in first post but over array. I updated my first post.

Comment: @CroiOS Have you solved your problem? Actually if you just wanna create an array and put several annotations in it. It's very easy.

Comment: Solved. Now I only don't know how to put image dynamically so I'll today post here source code ic you could take a look pls.